# How can I register several listeners on item click at ListView?

Tags: android, listview, click, listener

I have ListView, where any item is HorizontalLayout on wchich there are 3 TextView.
I can realize interface AdapterView.OnItemClickListener:

```
public void onItemClick(AdapterView parent, View view, final int position, long id) {
        final long iid = this.id;
        new Thread(
                new Runnable() {
                    public void run() {
                        long PlaylistId = PlayerServiceBridge.getPlaylistId();
                        if (PlaylistId == iid)
                            PlayerServiceBridge.setTrackByPosition(position);
                    }
                }
        ).start();
    }
```

Everything is right.
But now, I would like to scroll second out of 3 TextView horizontally.
I just add some code:

```
title.setSingleLine(true);
title.setMovementMethod(new ScrollingMovementMethod());
```

And now, when I click on Item where my TextView is, nothing occurs. When I click and move mouse - text on TextView is scrolled. It's ok. But onItemClick has never been called.
What do I need:
 1. I need just listen onItemClick when user just click on Item. 2. When user push down mouse on Item->TextView and then move mouse - just scroll text on thzt TextView. Second point is realized and works well. I need first at the same time with second)
 2. Added: public boolean onItemLongClick(AdapterView parent, View view, int position, long id) and public void onItemSelected(AdapterView parent, View view, int position, long id) are correctly listened and handled by my code. Why not onItemSelect?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've had the same problem. The trick is to make the descendants of the `LinearLayout` unfocusable. Basically, your `LinearLayout` has to have this attribute:

```
android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants"
```

Your `TextView` will still scroll.

Comment: This is almost a solution of my problem. Now I can click on any places  on Item and handle onItemClick. But, when I click on TextView, which is scrollable, nothing occurs(( How can I handle this situation when user "just click" on TextView on Item and "click and move mouse" on TextView on Item to scroll thix TextView?

Comment: @rauch you can set an onClickListener on the TextView and do the same thing you'd do in the item click listener :)